# Merging an array of paths to be used as a curve deformer

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying to make an array of paths to create something like a repeating wave pattern. The final pattern will be very long and would be a pain to do manually. What I want to be able to do, is merge the array of paths together, so it can be used as a curve deformer for another array of objects. This picture shows a simplified version of the problem. Currently the array of objects ends at the end of my initial (pre-array modifier) path. I am guessing it is thinking of each path as a separate object, but I need it to behave as if it is just the one. I have tried using the merge option in the array modifier, as well as the weld modifier, but neither have worked. Any ideas how this could be achieved?

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks Susu, I guess that’s what I am trying to do, make the array of paths connect somehow. I could do this manually by copying and pasting, but because it is going to be a repeated pattern and very long, I was hoping there would be a neater solution. Maybe it’s something that just isn’t possible. I was hoping someone might have tried to do something similar.

Comment: Did you try adding an array modifier to your mesh after your curve modifier ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the paths are connected (not just joined together in a single object) the array will not extend past the original curve.

Convert the curve to mesh, and then apply the array (making sure the merge option is enabled) that will give you a mesh with the shape of the arrayed curve.

Then convert the mesh back to curve and the other array should work as you want.

Comment: Thanks Susu, This is the approach I have gone with. It is defiantly better than doing it manually, but it does mean that I can’t make changes to the pattern or vary the length dynamically, which would have been nice.